# Image annotations that remain changeable

Tags: preview, image-editing

I want to edit images with annotations (text, arrows, ...). Preview does offer a nice set of tools but after saving they get embedded in the image and are not clickable/modifiable anymore. Using Time Machine to reset changes is much too cumbersome.

Do you know of any similar tools where i can *easily* alter annotations after saving (like [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) for PDFs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Skitch](http://evernote.com/skitch/)

[image: Skitch by Evernote]

Skitch is a very useful app for making annotations on images, and whilst by default it saves the files using the format that they are imported as, it can save it as a **Skitch PNG which keeps the ability to modify the annotations**, or the files can be kept inside its own library.